# Good front-end framework to use on top of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

Is there a good front-end framework to be used on top of jQuery? Stuff that takes care of many common tasks.

Comment: What kind of tasks are you referring to? UI elements,Databinding, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For UI Elements  (e.g. [Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs), [Accordions](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion), [Popups](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog), and more) and Effects (e.g. animations, [dragging](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), and more) the best framework out there is [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) as Deniz Dogan mentioned. It even has themes and a [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller) to roll your own theme.

However, JQuery UI doesn't handle any AJAX or Databinding.

[Ajax calls](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) are can be made with core framework alone. There may be plugins available to make those ajax calls easier when you are dealing with a large site. I haven't checked.

For [Templating and DataLanking](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/), there are new plugins available which will soon be added to the core framework (version 1.5) . (It still has the beta tag on it)

There are tons of [plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/) that add almost anything you can think of to the core framework. The main problem with plugins is the lack of support (depends on the plugin developer) while JQuery UI is constantly be maintained and updated.

Answer (score 3):

[JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) is what first comes to mind...

Answer (score 0):

I guess JqueryUI is the one u shud go with. You can even customize the themes for look and feel.